# How to Rewrite Internally in NGINX

Tags: nginx

I want to rewrite a URL location `/private/ping` to another location `/ping` once I've done some basic_auth checks.

When I call `http://localhost:8080/ping` I get OK.
When I call `http://localhost:8080/private/ping` I get OK only with the `#3` configuration. The other 2 configurations return 404.

I know NGINX is rewriting `/private/ping` to `/ping` successfully because the `#3` configuration returns `OK` but this generates an extra unnecessary HTTP request.

Why does NGINX not reprocess it's own rewrites checking them against existing locations or how can I make it do so?

```
server {

  listen 8080;

  location = /ping {
    return 200 'OK';
  }

  location /private/ {
    # basic_auth stuff here
    #rewrite ^/private/(.*) /$1 break; #1 No
    rewrite ^/private/(.*) /ping break; #2 No
    #proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/; #3 Yes
  }
```

Comment: Try using `last` instead of `break`

Comment: That's it! Thank you! Please post the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rewrite ... last` to restart the search for another `location` based on rewritten URI.